# How to hover over navigation items and open dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried methods of hovering over the navigation items but none seem to work. I want to do it in pure html/css if possible.

I tried using w3 schools method and a few other similar ones but not sure what I am doing wrong?

I want to accomplish this using only html/css since it seems to be possible but if not I can use javascript

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/k82g3nmh/

```html
<div id="navigation" class="clearfix">
  <ul id="nav" class="menu responsiveSelectFullMenu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-1114"><a href="" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
    <li class="megamenu columns-5 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1103"><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">eLibrary</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1132"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">Research</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1152"><a href="">General Research</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1151"><a href="">Business, Finance &amp; Job Searching</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1150"><a href="">Consumer &amp; DIY Information</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1149"><a href="">Family History</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1148"><a href="">Reading Resources</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1095"><a href="">Teens</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1097"><a href="">Kids</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1131"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">eBooks &amp; eAudiobooks</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4833"><a href="">Cloud Library</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4834"><a href="">Overdrive</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4851"><a href="">Loanable Kindles</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4695"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">Online Learning</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4703"><a href="">Rosetta Stone</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4696"><a href="">Gale Courses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1110"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">eMagazines</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1167"><a href="">RB Digital</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="megamenu columns-3 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1104"><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Your Library</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1140"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">What We Offer</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5176"><a href="">Library Rewards</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2377"><a href="">My Library Account</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1157"><a href="">Your Library Card</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1158"><a href="">Library Collection</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1138"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">Reference &amp; Reader Resources</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5308"><a href="">Hot Books</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1134"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">Other Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: 203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4510"><a href="">Passports</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1107"><a href="">Pay Online</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5539"><a href="">Museums</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1156"><a href="">Test Proctoring</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1113"><a class="sf-with-ul">About</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1127"><a href="" class="sf-with-ul">Library Board of Trustees</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; left: -203px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5540"><a href="">Certified Results of April 2 Election</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5412"><a href="">Library Budget Process</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4296"><a href="">Library Board Minutes &amp; Agendas</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3904"><a href="">Library Board Sponsorship Campaign</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1170"><a href="">Financials</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1129"><a href="">Policies</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1142"><a href="">Freedom of Information Act</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5110"><a href="">Library Volunteer Program</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4361"><a href="">Donations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the CSS so others can help you figure out what you might have done wrong

Comment: sorry I had it in the JSfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mustapha was almost right:

> `#navigation .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
>       display: block;
>   }`

on the end of the css.

Although it wouldn't work in the fiddle that you have provided. You also need to erase all inline styled `style="display:none"`there.
A working fiddle here: [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/16sr7faz/ .
I would recommand you to not use both inline styles and css, but i don't know your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this at the end of your CSS :

```css
#navigation .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't do it :(